# Updating the database tables with a new set of records without any latency in the UI display

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement where the data displayed in the UI needs to be the latest one. So, a .bat is written to update the database with the new set of data every 30 minutes. However, during the process the old data will be made to delete completely and fill with the new set of data. But, the issue is during this process, the UI will not be able to show any data, as the old data gets deleted as the first step in the process. So, is there anyway where I can update the DB table with new set of data while UI still displays the old data till the new data gets inserted? so that the UI will always some data to be displayed rather than showing no records?

Thanks,
Keerthi Kumar

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is totally unnecessary. And if you would have to rely on such a solution (in extreme cases), you would rename the table first, before you drop. You can rename many tables all at once in one atomic operation. But again, this solution is nonsense, no offense.

Comment: @fancyPants its early here, not enough caffine yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no other processes that write to this table during your update (which I assume takes a while)?

Then simply use a transaction.

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM your_table; /* Don't do a TRUNCATE TABLE; this would implicitly commit the transaction*/
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES('whatever');
COMMIT;
```

or

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE your_table SET column1 = 'new_value';
COMMIT;
```

Other threads will still read the old data until you `COMMIT`ed your transaction.

Please read more about transactions in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html). Also note, that this assumes you're using InnoDB engine tables.